# Cannot execute or open .jar files

Tags: java

hi have tried executing a .jar file using `java -jar jarfilename.jar` but it just returns:

`Error occurred during initialization of VM
 Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP`

and it returns the same thing if I use the command `java version`,`java -version`or`java --version`

Any reason why it doesn't work? (I have a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2

If you mean the (more or less) original single core pi with the yellow RCA and blue 3.5mm jacks, you can't run ARMv7 code.

You'll have to install a java build for ARMv6.

Comment: Yes I do. How would I install the java build for armv6 ?

Comment: Depends on what OS you are using, I guess.  You didn't say where you got this version either.  It *seems* to me that the default one in current Raspbian should be okay, but I'm not sure.  You might want to edit the output of `java --version` into your question.  The "server vm" is I believe a bit of a different beast than the normal one (which is the "client" version), dunno if that is the reason.

Comment: I downloaded the NOOBS recomended os, it came with java preinstalled.

Comment: NOOBs is actually an installer and not a complete OS, but it includes Raspbian; `cat /etc/issue` should give something like `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l`.  If it's a previous version, you should just replace what's on the card with plain Raspbian.  I dunno why they still recommend NOOBS, it seems to cause more trouble for people than anything else.

Comment: So, the fact that `java -version` returns the same message implies it's the JRE in general.  Check `which java`.  Although I think not many people are still using the original B's, the Zeros have the same processor and it so the OS still has to be ARMv6 compatible.

Comment: `which java` just gives me `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: That's openJDK then.  If the OS is Raspbian 10, that's weird.  You could try installing the Oracle JRE if you can find an ARMv6 package -- [there used to be one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/oracle-java-on-raspberry-pi/) available via Raspbian, but I dunno what happened to that.